# Integrate working strangely

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function:

```
f=-((2 x \[Xi]x \[Xi]z^3 (A*B) UnitBox[1/10 (-5 + x + \[Xi]x)] UnitBox[
   1/2 - z - \[Xi]z])/(\[Xi]x^2 + \[Xi]z^2)^(3/2))
```

where A and B are two constants. I want to integrate the functions along the following domain:

```
ℛ=ImplicitRegion[-10 + x + \[Xi]x == 0 && 
0 <= x <= 10 && -5 <= \[Xi]x <= 5 && -0.5 <= \[Xi]z <= 0.5 && 
0 <= z <= 1, {x, z, \[Xi]x, \[Xi]z}]
```

Therefore I wrote:

```
Integrate[f, {x, z, ξx, ξz} ∈ ℛ]
```

which gave as a result:

```
1.88411*10^-11 A B
```

Then, I tried to take the constants away, i.e.

```
g=f/(A B)

A*B*Integrate[g, {x, z, ξx, ξz} ∈ ℛ]
```

but what I get as a result is:

```
1.05957*10^-11 A B
```

which is the exact same result as if I write:

```
A*B*NIntegrate[g, {x, z, ξx, ξz} ∈ ℛ]
```

I know the correct result is the first one, so I am wondering what is happening

Answer (score 1):

If you define the region analytically (`1/2`instaed of `0.5`)

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[-7 + x + ξx == 0 && 0 <= x <= 10 && -5 <= ξx <= 5 && -0.5 <= ξz <= 0.5 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, z, ξx, ξz}] // Rationalize
```

you'll get nonnumeric results in both cases!

```
Integrate[f, {x, z, ξx, ξz} ∈ ℛ]

(*4/5 Sqrt[2] A B (1625 Log[6] - 929 Log[10] + 1625 Log[6/(-1 + Sqrt[37])] - 1625 Log[1 + Sqrt[37]] -929 Log[10/(-1 + Sqrt[101])] + 929 Log[1 + Sqrt[101]])*)

Integrate[f/(A B), {x, z, ξx, ξz} ∈ ℛ]

(*4/5 Sqrt[2] (1625 Log[6] - 929 Log[10] + 1625 Log[6/(-1 + Sqrt[37])] - 1625 Log[1 + Sqrt[37]] -929 Log[10/(-1 + Sqrt[101])] + 929 Log[1 + Sqrt[101]])*)
```